# Python: create beeping audible feedback of which pause duration is based upon real-time sensor input

Tags: python, audio

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm attempting to develop a function that operates more or less like a parking sensor in a car.

That is: the code receives some sensor input data and in real-time a beeping sound is created of which the wait period between two beeps is inversely related to the magnitude of the signal (i.e., when close the beeps are close together and vice versa).

I've attempted to create a while loop that includes winsound.beep() and a pause. The pause duration will be calculated using the sensor input. However, even when run as a few lines of simple code the while loop seems asynchronous and the pauses aren't evenly spaced apart.

I attempted to put the code in a separate thread but this did not solve the problem.

I'll include the code here to just perform a repeated beeping sound, not taking any input yet to troubleshoot from there.

```py
from time import sleep
import winsound

while True:
    winsound.Beep(1500,100)
    sleep(0.05)
```

I expect the output to be a consistent beep spaced 0.05s apart, but the actual output is asynchronous beeping with the pauses varying with time.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from time import sleep
import winsound

while True:

    winsound.Beep("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
    sleep(0.05)
```

Edit :
Try this

```
from time import sleep
import winsound

while True:
    frequency = 10 # change it based on sensor input
    duration = 1000 # keep this constant
    winsound.Beep(frequency,duration)
    sleep(duration) # i'm assuming beep is not blocking so this delay keep the program waiting until beep duration is completed
```

Beep Takes the parameters frequency and duration. 
So instead of changing the sleep duration, you can change the frequency to match the magnitude of signal.

Comment: Yes, this works but SystemExit (or any other native windows sounds) are relatively long. I need a short beep (alike the beep defined above which takes only 100ms) that is repeated over and over again. Again, I need something like the behavior of a parking sensor.